# increment jquery varibles

Tags: jquery, loops, increment

I have this code to create variables with different id(s), as you can see here:

```
var numgrid = jQuery('.panel-grid').length;

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-0")[0])
{   var os0 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-0").offset().top;
    var pg0 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-0").attr('id');   }   

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-1")[0])
{   var os1 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-1").offset().top;
    var pg1 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-1").attr('id');   }        

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-2")[0])
{   var os2 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-2").offset().top;
    var pg2 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-2").attr('id');   } 

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-3")[0])
{   var os3 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-3").offset().top;
    var pg3 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-3").attr('id');   } 

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-4")[0])
{   var os4 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-4").offset().top;
    var pg4 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-4").attr('id');   }

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-5")[0])
{   var os5 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-5").offset().top;
    var pg5 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-5").attr('id');   }

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-6")[0])
{   var os6 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-6").offset().top;
    var pg6 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-6").attr('id');   }

if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-7")[0])
{   var os7 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-7").offset().top;
    var pg7 = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-7").attr('id');   }
```

Now I want to make this code shorter and only create the same amount of variables of the class ".panel-grid" that exists. I am a beginner in jQuery.
I hope someone can help me make a loop to increment the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be:

```
var os = [];
var pg = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if (jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-"+i)[0]){
     os[i] = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-"+i).offset().top;
     pg[i] = jQuery("#pg-"+id+"-"+i).attr('id');
  }
}
```

Comment: Im note sure if it the right way to show the variable of an array in the consolte. I used this  console.log(pg2, 'id'); This gave me this error that pg2 is not defined

Comment: @benjamin-seifert  `console.log(pg[2]);`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than thinking of creating dynamic variables what about creating an array?

```
var os = [];
for (var i = 0; i < yourVariableLength; ++i) {
    os[i] = // getting your variable values;
}
```